# What is the Google BigQuery equivalent AWS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I heard Athena is data analytics service from AWS which provides the same features like big query. Can we use Athena as alternative product for bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

Athena is often used as a SQL layer for structured data in S3 such as formatted logs rather than a production DB like BigQuery which brings built-in multi-region support, etc. The AWS equivalent would still be a dedicated DB, either Postgres for SQL or Dynamo for NoSQL.